# How does Google power the box at the top of my search results?

Tags: seo

What powers the little box that sometimes show up at the top of search results with things like: definitions for words, weather, movie times, and sometimes even the precise steps in a cooking recipe?

Because I recently searched for a recipe and google showed me the steps for making the recipe right at the top of my results.

Curious to know how they did this, I checked the source of the content and to my surprise, there was no [structured data / rich snippets][1]. There were no special meta tags either and the page didn't even use HTML5 elements.

There was nothing in the markup that would signify the relationship between a step in making the recipe and the details within the steps - we're talking plain old divs, p's, and h tags. There were also no class or div names that Google could have used to piece it together (eg. , etc)

So, how do they do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about seo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does this using the knowledge graph. You can help get your data in there by using structured data markup (look at http://schema.org)